# DNS/Mailboxes for subdomain currently on an exchange

Tags: domain-name-system, email, exchange, mailbox

A client currently has emails such as:

`user@uk.domain.com`

they have these two A records (among others, to different IPs):

```
uk.domain.com
mail.domain.com
```

pointing to the same IP address.

There is only one mx record - `domain.com --> mail.domain.com`

I believe they are on an exchange at the moment, whether that makes any difference.

I am to transfer control of mail to our own server, which is not an exchange.
Is this task as simple as:

creating a subdomain `uk.domain.com`

and pointing the `A` records to the IP of the new mail server?

Answer (score 0):

Change/update the MX record to point to the new email host (which should be an existing A record in your DNS zone).